# What could be causing this washer to rattle very loud sometimes?

Tags: appliances

I've read online that this could be due to the bearings being worn out on the washer, but before I go ordering a replacement part I'd like to get a 2nd opinion.  Does this look/sound like it's the bearings?  This ONLY happens during the wash cycle...

Here's the [video/sample noise](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APZCIbwc_Ag)

It's very loud, but towards the end it shows what it really sounds like.

Here's an up close picture: [image]
[image]

The sound you hear in the video is a rattling sound that is coming from the bottom of the washer.  Behind the silver box.

Comment: It's not really clear from your question what, exactly, the symptom is.  Is it the predominant high frequency sound in the video?  If so, I'm not confident that I'm hearing an earnest reproduction of it which makes it difficult to offer second opinion.  Or, is it the amount or nature of motion of the basin you are concerned about?

Comment: The sound is what tells me something is wrong.  It doesn't sound exactly the same in the video as when we hear it.  I'm not sure how else to portray what's going on... it sounds like it's coming from the bottom middle of the washer.  Like that disc behind the silver block in the bottom picture.  It's so loud though it's hard to tell exactly.

Comment: I'd unplug it and try to manually rotate the possible culprits. You may feel the problem, or at least be able to get your ear closer to hear exactly where it's coming from.

Comment: Cheap washers tend to be absurdly loud because they use cheaper parts, so I would wager you will do nothing but waste time chasing dragons.  This is just my honest opinion.

Comment: hard to tell, but the screechy high freq noise kinda does sound like metal spinning on metal, like a worn bearing.